# move datagridview Row to another datagridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, move

I've gone through the other answers for this kind of question, nothing has really worked well so far.

I have a `foreach` loop that should add the the row from the source `datagridview` to the destination `datagridview` then remove that row from the source.

The invalid operation exception is: `Row provided already belongs to a DataGridView control.`

I couldn't get `...Rows.Copy()` to work either. Any ideas?

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow selRow in fromDataGridView.SelectedRows)
{
    toDataGridView.Rows.Add(selRow);
    fromDataGridView.Rows.Remove(selRow);
}
```

Comment: you need to do this in a for loop not a foreach loop and you need to do the count in the reverse order if that makes sense..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove the row from `fromDataGridView` before you add it to `toDataGridView`.

But you're modifying the collection inside the `foreach` loop - that won't work.

The workaround is to copy the collection for use in the `foreach`.

Try this:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow selRow in fromDataGridView.SelectedRows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>().ToArray())
{
    fromDataGridView.Rows.Remove(selRow);
    toDataGridView.Rows.Add(selRow);
}
```

Comment: `Error 1 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection' does not contain a definition for 'ToArray' and no extension method 'ToArray' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` i did add `using System.Collections;`

Comment: Updated and you need a `using System.Linq;`

Comment: @RoyGoode : I have error like this: `Rows cannot be programmatically added to the DataGridView's rows collection when the control is data-bound.` at row `toDataGridView.Rows.Add(selRow);`.

Comment: @VănLộc Sounds like you have data-bound your DataGridView to an object, such as a DataSet, DataTable, List or Dictionary. When you do that, you'll have to control the rows in the DataGridView by manipulating the source object that you specified in the BindingSource.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of what you could do or try..

its happening when one row is removed the rows count decrements too so if you put your code in for loop and run it in reverse it would work fine have a look:

```
for (int selRow = dataGridView1.Rows.Count -1; selRow >= 0 ; selRow--)
{
   toDataGridView.Rows.Add(selRow);
   fromDataGridView.Rows.Remove(selRow);     
}
```

Comment: this failed on the `Add` line. "Number of copies to create must be strictly positive." Parameter is count.

Comment: It`s because selRow must be > 0

Answer (score 0):

Adding a new row directly to `DataGridView` is not possible when there is `BindingSource`.

You should add row to the `BindingSource` of second view and let it to add the row to its grid.

I've tested the below code in a working solution.

```
var selectedRows = dataGridView1.SelectedRows;
int count = dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count;
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    bindingSource2.Add(bindingSource1[selectedRows[i].Index]);
    dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(selectedRows[i]);
}
```

Comment: how to i set/reference/change the binding sources for the two datagridviews?

Comment: @ikathegreat I don't get your aim from the above comment. Does your grid connected to `BindingSource` or not?