# How to transfer selected rows from one datagridview to another?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I try to transfer selected rows from one datagridview to another. I used combobox textchange event to load selected data to datagrid. So that transfer code need to do `dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;` for both `dataGridView`s. But due to use combobox textchange event I can't disable adding new rows. How to solve this? I use following code to transfer values:

```
private void btnaddtoanother_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= dataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            bool rowAlreadyExist = false;
            bool checkedCell = (bool)dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value;
            if (checkedCell == true)
            {
                DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView2.Rows[i];
                if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count != 0)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j <= dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; j++)
                    {
                        if (row.Cells[0].Value.ToString() == dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[0].Value.ToString())
                        {
                            rowAlreadyExist = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (rowAlreadyExist == false)
                    {
                        dataGridView2.Rows.Add(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
                        dataGridView2.Rows.Add(row.Cells[1].Value.ToString());
                        dataGridView2.Rows.Add(row.Cells[3].Value.ToString());
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    dataGridView2.Rows.Add(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
                    dataGridView2.Rows.Add(row.Cells[1].Value.ToString());
                    dataGridView2.Rows.Add(row.Cells[3].Value.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you disable adding new rows you can still *programmatically* add new rows, it just means that the user can't add new rows using the UI

Comment: I really do not understand the question. Do you want to create a copy or do you want to move rows? What has the combobox to do with it?

Comment: @TaW I want to move rows.And that combobox I used to select GRN_No(Primary key of GRN table) and load data to datagrid according to GRN_No

Comment: Then [try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9265165/move-datagridview-row-to-another-datagridview) unless they are data bound.

Answer (score 0):

Start with removing the row from the Grid before you try to add it to the new Grid.

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in fromGridView.SelectedRows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>().ToArray())
{
    fromGridView.Rows.Remove(row);
    toGridView.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Comment: Where I should use this?